# How to use a custom MediaSource for a virtual camera? Also, how and where should I register the CLSID for my virtual camera?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation, c++-winrt

I'm working on a C++ UWP application using the Microsoft Media Foundation library. My app aims to create a virtual camera that can use a video file as its video source.

Virtual camera creation:

```
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateVirtualCamera(
    MFVirtualCameraType_SoftwareCameraSource,
    MFVirtualCameraLifetime_Session,
    MFVirtualCameraAccess_CurrentUser,
    cameraName,
    L"{7B89B92E-FE71-42D0-8A41-E137D06EA184}",
    nullptr,
    0,
    pVirtualCamera.put()
));
```

I get an "Class not registered" error when I try to start the virtual camera created above. I understand that it's because of the above mentioned CLSID not being registered in the registry. So, how and where exactly in the registry do I register my CLSID?

Secondly,
I understand that there's a `IMFMediaSource` linked to the virtual camera that I can obtain this way:

```
winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaSource> pMediaSource;
pVirtualCamera->GetMediaSource(pMediaSource.put());
```

So, how do I replace it with a new MediaSource that uses the video file as the actual source? Also, please mention if I'm missing something and there's a completely different way  to go about doing this.

Comment: Did Microsoft sample work for you?

Comment: @RomanR. I did try to understand it. But, I am still unable to get the overall summary/outline of how it all fits together and works especially for my use case.

Comment: @RomanR. can you give me any pointers, please? Like a brief summary of what's the right way to do things for my use case would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: But did their sample work for you? That is, their sample works and if you don't understand how and you don't see parts of this sample and how they communicate one another how we can discuss your question.

Comment: For information, I've created another simple which I believe is more simple than the Microsoft one, it's available here https://github.com/smourier/VCamSample

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you so much! It will be a life saver for me.